# Thread synchronization - writer priority locks

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads

So, I am using C on a unix system and have access to the pthreads & semaphore.h libraries.

Here is the problem (I believe this boils down to a "writer priority rw lock" problem):

For simplicities sake, I have two different processes that a thread can run: A & B.

B is more important than A, and thus if there is ever a B waiting to run, I do not want any more A processes to start executing until all of the B processes have run. Additionally, while multiple A processes can run concurrently, only 1 B process can execute at a time.

The current way I am doing this (which I believe to either be wrong, inefficient, or both) is to have the B processes require a lock for their entire execution time and the A processes will acquire and immediately release the lock at the beginning of their execution. I am also using semaphores here to allow for the multi-reader/single writer functionality.

For various reasons, the pthread_rwlock functionality is not usable on this system, so the solution can't involve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A is going to immediately release the lock, but continue using whatever resource it is that you want to lock, then why do you even bother locking to begin with?

You said:
-Multiple A's can run simultaneously
-Only one B can run at a time

I'm assuming (but correct me if I'm wrong):
-B and A cannot run at the same time

If you immediately release the lock from A then that's going to allow a B to run at the same time.  Am I missing anything here?

The solution:

Have a mechanism that gets the resource for the a threads.  That mechanism only puts a lock on the resource one time when the first A thread starts and releases it only when all A threads are gone.

Have a cancel token for the A threads to use that gets set to true when a B thread begins, then when all A threads have exited the B thread can begin.

The B thread obviously locks and doesn't release until it's completed.

Don't forget to check the cancel token frequently enough in the A thread so that it doesn't take too long to exit when asked.

Comment: I'm not sure how you've got it setup, but in order to accomplish what you want with a locking mechanism it sounds like you'd need a way to share the resource between A thread's.  Then you'd lock the first time an A thread starts and just keep a tally of how many A threads are running.  When the count reaches 0 you can release the lock.

Comment: So, 2 things: 
1. The immediate grab and release of the lock makes it so that if a writer grabs this lock, then any future read requests are put on hold until the current ones finish and the write request finishes. I am using semaphores much in the way described in the above comment to prevent reads/writes from happening at the same time. 
2. the above comment would work, but it would not be writer priority. IE. an infinite number of read requests could come in and even if a write request was waiting, it would never execute because the "read" thread(s) already had the lock.

Comment: Okay, so a read begins and grabs/releases the lock.  While that read is 'still' occurring a write process wants to start.  Because the lock was released your program is going to let both occur at the same time... but we already discussed this is bad, right?  By immediately releasing the lock your are defeating the purpose of having the lock in the first place.  Why even bother to lock at all if you're going to release it right away while the process is still running, what benefit does it give you?

Comment: You should have your A threads lock in the manner I explained above, but you'll need a cancel token you can set to notify all A threads that they need to exit immediately (which means the the reader threads need to check the cancel token periodically so they don't take too long to exit when asked).  Then when they've all exited the lock will be released and the write can begin.